# jQuery - TableSorter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cant seem to figure out why the tablesorter jQuery plugin does not seem to work. I have included both the JavaScript files and the css file (although not required) and initialized it. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath()?>/js/sortable.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#supplierTable").tablesorter();
    });
</script>

<table class="tablesorter table table-striped table-hover table-curved" id="supplierTable" name="supplierTable">
```

Comment: put jquery link first then other links comes..

Comment: More comprehensive: The jQuery api must be loaded first because the plugin scripts rely on jQuery. When you load scripts out of order, you will receive errors i.e. *"$ is undefined"*.

Comment: @shri Doesnt seem to make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you load the jQuery TableSorter plugin script and a theme, you need to pass the theme that you have loaded into the `jQuery.tablesorter` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#supplierTable").tablesorter({
    // Select the theme that was loaded through CSS.
    theme: 'ice',

    // The default sorter will not work for the provided cell data.
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: 'text' },
      1: { sorter: 'text' },
      2: { sorter: 'text' }
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Load jQuery if not already loaded. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the TableSorter plugin. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load a theme i.e. "ice". -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.5/css/theme.ice.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="supplierTable" name="supplierTable" class="tablesorter table table-striped table-hover table-curved">
  <thead>
    <tr> <th>A</th> <th>B</th> <th>C</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>0.0, 0</td> <td>1.1, 0</td> <td>2.2, 0</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>0.1, 1</td> <td>1.2, 1</td> <td>2.0, 1</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>0.2, 2</td> <td>1.0, 2</td> <td>2.1, 2</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. This code snippet does indeed work. However, im pulling my table data through a database. Is the reason it is not working because they have text? The main column I want to update is distance i.e. 10.6 KM

Comment: Had a look at my code again. It turns out that I was including <tbody></tbody> inside my while loop which results in unable to perform the sort. Typical! Wont be making that mistake again.. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues that I can see:

First,
The order you include JS libraries matters. You have to take dependencies into account. This means you cannot load one library that is dependant on another before the one it is dependant on. In this case, sortable.js is dependant on JQuery library and so therfore must be loaded after.

Second,
The documentation for the sortable.js says you need to class your table as "sortable".

So try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath()?>/js/sortable.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#supplierTable").tablesorter();
        });
    </script>

    <table class="tablesorter table table-striped table-hover table-curved sortable" id="supplierTable" name="supplierTable">
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have renamed that file, it is using the jQuery Tablesorter plugin. Also, im using concrete5, which already uses JQuery plugin so I dont actually need that line. Source http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/27/make-html-table-sortable-jquery-tablesorter-plugin